# Why does Jenkins fail to git init and return status code 1?

Tags: git, unix, plugins, jenkins

**Scenario**

- We have two build slaves (`xcode7` and `xcode2`) running the exact same instance of Mac OS X El Capitan and both with the same build tools (Xcode 7.3).
- There is a user account set up in the Jenkins SSH Slave Plugin credential named 'superbuilder' and it provides credentials when SSH is started via a private key and passphrase. `superbuilder` is a user exists on both build slaves and has matching private keys and public keys on both machines.
- One of those slaves (`xcode2`) can clone our repo and the other (`xcode7`) can't because `git init` fails `with status code 1:` (see stack trace below).

**Versions of things**

- Jenkins version: `1.580.1`
- Git plugin version: `1.13.3`
- SSH Slave Plugin version: `1.9`
- Git version on both machines: `2.6.4 (Apple Git-63)`

**What have I tried on xcode7**

- Extensive searching for Jenkins bugs and "status code 1:".
- Ensuring that the `superbuilder` user has the exact same public, private keys and known hosts as it does on `xcode2`.
- SSH'ing into `xcode7` directly and calling the exact same git clone commands locally. This succeeds and I am able to manually clone the repo.
- Ensured that the `git` binary is available is visible to the `superbuilder` on its $PATH.
- Ensured that `buildmaster` has read/write/execute permissions on the jenkins workspace directory.
- Ensured that `DEVELOPER_DIR` is injected an environment variable and points at `/Applications/Xcode`

**Questions**

- Is `xcrun error` relevant? By that I mean is *that* the source of my problem or is it something else?
- What does `status code 1` refer to?
- Why would `git init` fail when run through the Jenkins SSH Slave Plugin?
- Can I buy you a beer if you help with this?
- Is this real life?

**Stack Trace from Jenkins Build Job**

```
[EnvInject] - Mask passwords passed as build parameters.
Started by user anonymous
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building remotely on xcode7-xcode (xcode7) in workspace /var/jenkins/workspace/mobile.iphone-app-xcode7.ci
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@git.somecorp.com:mobile/iphone-app.git
 > git init /var/jenkins/workspace/mobile.iphone-app-xcode7.ci # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /var/jenkins/workspace/mobile.iphone-app-xcode7.ci
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:656)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:463)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:152)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:324)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at ......remote call to xcode7-xcode(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1356)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:221)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:752)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.execute(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1057)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1097)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:488)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1253)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:622)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:528)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1745)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git init /var/jenkins/workspace/mobile.iphone-app-xcode7.ci" returned         status code 1:
stdout: 
stderr: xcrun: error: missing DEVELOPER_DIR path: /Applications/Xcode
...
```

Comment: This looks relevant: `error: missing DEVELOPER_DIR path: /Applications/Xcode`

Comment: Does `/Applications/Xcode` exist on xcode7?

Comment: It doesn't. But I also removed that ENV variable from being injected on the `xcode7-code` Jenkins configuration screen.

Comment: I am not sure if that's my issue, either.

Comment: `echo $DEVELOPER_DIR` on both machines when SSH'ing in prints nothing to the standard output.

Comment: @mkasberg I think you might have been right about that weird ENV variable. I was previously injecting that whenever we spun up a connection to that slave, but I stopped injecting it but I never restarted the machine. I cycled the slave machine and now that previously injected ENV variable is gone. If you drop an answer relative to that I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: ^^ All that to say is my build proceeds now and I'm on to the next error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that it's complaining about is `error: missing DEVELOPER_DIR path: /Applications/Xcode`. Is that variable set on both machines? Is is the same on both machines? Does the directory exist and contain the same thing on both machines?

Comment: You're right. That was the fishy thing about it all. I removed the injection of this variable, power cycled the slave machine and the `status code 1` error message was resolved. Thanks to @mkasberg for opening my eyes to the obvious thing I was ignoring.

Answer (score 1):

I hope update Jenkins to newest version helps

This bug found and fixed at `Jenkins 1.509.4`

[See](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20257)

I Think you can try to create remote working dir manual and run this command from console. This will be some kind of workaround

Comment: This is great info and probably also part of my problem.